# Expectation of a random variable probabilistically defined in terms of other random variables

Tags: expected-value

For instance,
$$X = \begin{cases} Y, & \text{with probability} ~0.3,\\
Z, & \text{with probability} ~0.7, \end{cases}$$
where $Y$ and $Z$ are random variables with known distributions.

How does one find the expectation of $X$

Comment: One applies a definition or an equivalent formula.  An attractive one for this application is the [tower formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=tower+expect*+is%3Aanswer+score%3A2), aka the law of iterated expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @whuber commented, the representation of $X$ is conditional on $Y$ and $Z$. That is, conditional on $Y$ and $Z$, $X$ behaves like a Bernoulli random variable. Therefore,
$$
E(X\mid Y,Z) = 0.3 Y + 0.7Z.
$$
This gives us $E(X) = 0.3E(Y) + 0.7 E(Z)$. A minor remark would be that what you wrote in the original post is typically how we construct a mixture distribution.

Comment: In other words, $X=BY+(1-B)Z$ where $B \sim \text{Bernoulli}(0.3)$, independent of $Y,Z$.